# Trying to figure out the probability of sick days for an employee who I think is lying

Tags: probability

We have recorded $7$ individual sick days with $4$ of the sick days falling on a Monday which is a little suspicious. Let's assume that there are no public holidays and it is just a standard working week, Monday to Friday.

What is the probability/chance of this?

It would be helpful to understand how to work this out!

Comment: It's hard to say something accurate here, let alone use this as proof against an employee. One *can* do a naive calculation if you know the distribution of sick days among the average employee to get a number for this. However people are very different so there might be a good reason for the sick days. IMO *talking* about this to the employee is the way to go, not computing probabillities.

Comment: not trying to use it as proof, I just thought it'd be fun to try and work it out or understand it, I don't have a good understanding of maths like a lot of people on this site so I was trying to understand the logic of how to work out this problem out. I wouldn't want to bring distribution of sick days into it but rather approach it from a 1 out of 5 chance of falling sick on a Monday... does that make sense?

Comment: When I had a similar situation to deal with I just pointed out the co-incidence to my employee and it stopped happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You might spend less time wondering about peoples' sick days. :-)

It depends a lot on what you consider suspicious, and also (possibly) how many employees you're keeping tabs on.

In the most restrictive case, you only consider Monday suspicious, and are only keeping tabs on this one employee.  In that case, the probability (given the null hypothesis that the employee is equally likely to be sick on any given day of the week) that at *least* four of seven sick days fall on a Monday is

\begin{align}
P & = \binom{7}{4} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^4 \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^3 \\
  & + \binom{7}{5} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^5 \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2 \\
  & + \binom{7}{6} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^6 \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^1 \\
  & + \binom{7}{7} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^7 \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^0 \\
  & = \frac{2240+336+28+1}{78125} \\
  & = \frac{2605}{78125} = \frac{521}{15625} \doteq 0.033344
\end{align}

or about $1$ chance in $30$.  Just to be clear, that is *not* the probability that the employee is malingering.  It is the probability, given that the employee is *not* malingering, that they would exhibit this sort of sick-day record.  This level of result is generally not considered statistically significant.

And note that this is given that you're only looking at one employee.  If you work in an office with ten employees, say, it's far more likely that you'll notice one employee with this kind of record, purely by dumb luck, even if none of them is malingering.  The probability there is given by

$$
P = 1 - \left(1-\frac{521}{15625}\right)^{10} \doteq 0.28761
$$

or over a $1$ in $4$ chance that at least one of the employees will be out at least four Mondays out of seven sick days.  It's really not that unusual.

And furthermore, this assumes that *only* Mondays are suspicious.  Why shouldn't Fridays be suspicious, too?  That raises the odds of a completely innocent trend correspondingly.

Comment: thanks so much for this, was just curious as to how to work this out, won't be providing it as evidence or anything and rest assured to everyone else it is being handled in a proper way :-)

Comment: In general, Bayes theorem is useful (especially in more complicated cases).

Comment: Usually, I take a Bayesian approach. But this simpler approach seemed more appropriate here somehow.